# 大辞泉 dictionary notation -- ① ㋐ ㋑ ㋒ ㋓ ㋔

Tags: definitions, dictionary

In 大辞泉 what is the meaning of the symbols ㋐㋑㋒㋓㋔?

For example they all appear in this definition:

> あぶら【油・脂・×膏】
> ①水に溶けず、水よりも軽い可燃性物質の総称。動物性・植物性・鉱物性があり、食用・灯火用・燃料用・化学工業の原料など用途が広い。㋐動物の肉についている脂肪分。脂身（あぶらみ）。「―の多い切り身」㋑皮膚から分泌する脂肪。「汗と―の結晶」㋒植物の種子などからとれる液体。菜種油・ごま油など。「―で揚げる」㋓原油を精製したもの。重油・軽油・灯油など。㋔髪油。ポマードやチック類もいう。「―でなでつける」②活力のみなもと。特に酒をさすことが多い。「疲れたから―を補給しよう」③《火に油を注ぐとよく燃えるところから》おせじ。へつらい。うれしがらせ。「えらい―言ひなます」〈滑・膝栗毛・八〉

Comment: 意味・用法の区分を示す標準的な記号としては１　２を用いた。その下位の区分としては㋐㋑を用いた。[here](https://www.weblio.jp/shogakukan.jsp#8)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a specific dictionary's notations, not about the Japanese language.  This would be better answered in chat.

Comment: @istrasci I think it is a rather common way of having "bullet points" in Japanese. I see no problem with this question.

Comment: It’s analogous to 1a, 1b, etc. in English enumeration. They are sub-points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to read the definitions?

The circled numbers are separating broad differences in meaning.  The circled katakana are providing subsenses within a particular broad meaning.

This seems to be following pretty standard dictionary practices. Whether in English or Japanese.